# Proving set $(0,1)\times\{0\} \subseteq\mathbb{R^2}$ is not open.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Can I please get some help/feedback on my proof? Thank you.
$\def\R{{\mathbb R}}                            
\def\Rhat{{\widehat{\R}}}                  
\def\N{{\mathbb N}}$

$(0,1)$ is open in $\R$.  I will prove that, when considered as a subset of $\R^2$, that is, as a line segment on the $x$-axis in the plane, it is not open. Specifically, I will show that the set $(0,1)\times\{0\} \subseteq\R^2$ is not open.

$\textbf{Solution:}$ Consider the set $(0,1) \times \{0\} \subset \R^2.$ A set $S$ is called open if every point of the set $S$ is an interior point, that is, for every point $x\in S$, there exist an open set $V$, such that $x\in V \subset S.$

Pick the point $p = (\frac{1}{2}, 0)$ inside $(0,1) \times \{0\}$. In $\R^2$, the open balls form a basis for the topology of $\R^2$, meaning every point $x$ in $\R^2$, we can find an open ball containing it and if an open set $U$ contains $x$, there exists an open ball centered at $x$ such that $x\in B \subset U$. So, if we can show there do not exist any open ball centered at $p = (\frac{1}{2}, 0)$ contained in $(0,1) \times \{0\}$, we will be done.

Now, we will show why no open ball sits inside $(0,1) \times \{0\}$ by supposing it is, that is, there is an open ball $B(p,r)$, for some $r>0$,  in the Euclidean metric on $\Bbb R^2$ such that $$B(p,r) \subseteq (0,1) \times \{0\}\tag{1}$$

But $q=(\frac12, \frac{r}{2})$ obeys $d(p,q)=\frac{r}{2}< r$, so that $q \in B(p,r)$ but as $\frac{r}{2} \neq 0$, $q \notin (0,1) \times \{0\}$. This contradicts our supposed inclusion $(1)$. So $p$ is not an interior point of $(0,1) \times \{0\}$ and $(0,1) \times \{0\}$ is not open.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to show the complement of that set is not closed?

Comment: @DonAntonio I think but I am not able to, I posted it earlier and my proof for that was far off apparently so I hope this is better but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: That's a very thorough answer. Do you really need all of the stuff about bases? I've always thought the standard definition of an interior point is that there exists a neighborhood that is contained within the set. In your definition, you say there exists an open set, which is true, but more complicated than just sticking with neighborhoods.

Comment: Using a local base is not necessary. Just the open ball definiton of interior.

Comment: It seems like you did a lot of *talking* to say basic concepts, which is fine, always err on more than less when you are learning, but then the entire gyst is this sentence " Now, for any n∈N, the open ball B1/n(p) do not lie inside the set (0,1)×{0}" which is stated as fact without any verification.

Comment: Now with the edit it is absolutely correct. But it is unnecessarily wordy. I don't want to discourage students to be more thorough when in doubt but you take it to an almost farcical extreme.  enough to say: for any $\epsilon > 0$ that $k=(\frac 12,\frac 12\epsilon)\in (0,1)\times\{0\}$ but $k\in B_\epsilon(\frac 12,0)$ so $(\frac 12,0)$ can not be an interior point.  ... and I have 185 characters left to spare!

Comment: But to be encouraging.... Yes, your proof *is* absolutely correct and shows good understanding of the concepts.  Full marks.

Comment: @fleablood thank you for the feedback and help with this. I believe the local basis paragraph was not necessary as Henno indicated, so I removed it.

Comment: @fleablood so I have the proof drawn out in the form of a picture but that is no proof. So, I tried forming the words to prove it properly lol

Comment: There is an unfortunate side effect of having removed 80% of the text of the question, which is that many portions of the comments and of the accepted answer, which were referring to the original text, are now nonsense because they do not refer to anything.

Comment: @LeeMosher I am terribly sorry, accidental edit. I put it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is fine: show that e.g. $p=(\frac12,0)$ is not an interior point of $(0,1) \times \{0\}$. But you do *not* show **why** no open ball sits inside $(0,1) \times \{0\}$, you need to fill that gap (e.g. a picture is not a proof!)

So suppose it is, so there is an open ball $B(p,r)$, for some $r>0$,  in the Euclidean metric on $\Bbb R^2$ such that $$B(p,r) \subseteq (0,1) \times \{0\}\tag{1}$$

But $q=(\frac12, \frac{r}{2})$ obeys $d(p,q)=\frac{r}{2}< r$, so that $q \in B(p,r)$ but as $\frac{r}{2} \neq 0$, $q \notin (0,1) \times \{0\}$. This contradicts our supposed inclusion $(1)$. So $p$ is not an interior point of $(0,1) \times \{0\}$ and $(0,1) \times \{0\}$ is not open.

Comment: Thank you Henno for the feedback and help. Do you think I should just remove the local basis claim? I made an edit to my solution to include yours. I am trying to reread this, it is easier to prove these sort of things by picture but proof by picture is not a proof lol

Comment: @rudinsimons12 yes, remove the local base bit. A picture gives the idea for a rigorous argument.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea: take for example the sequence

$$\left\{\left(\frac12\,,\,\frac1n\right)\right\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$$

Check that the above sequence is **not** in the set $\;E:=(0,1)\times\{0\}\;$, so it belongs to $\;E^c=\Bbb R^2\setminus E\;$ . The sequence is clearly convergent, so if $\;E^c\;$ is closed it must contain this sequence's limit, yet

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac12\,,\,\frac1n\right)=\left(\frac12,\,0\right)\in E$$

which means $\;E^c\;$ is not closed and thus $\;(E^c)^c=E\;$ is not open. $\;\;\;\;\;\;\blacksquare\;$